# Github-permission denied

Tags: git, github, version-control

```
psis-Mac-mini:doordie psi$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
psis-Mac-mini:doordie psi$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/psi/Desktop/Development/doordie/.git/
psis-Mac-mini:doordie psi$ git add .
psis-Mac-mini:doordie psi$ git commit -m "First commit"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
psis-Mac-mini:doordie psi$ git remote add origin https://github.com/suresh/sample.git

psis-Mac-mini:doordie psi$ git push origin master
remote: Permission to suresh/sample.git denied to priya.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/suresh/sample.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
psis-Mac-mini:doordie psi$
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have the permissions to push because you're using the http url. You should use the ssh url:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:suresh/sample.git
git push origin master
```

Comment: psis-Mac-mini:sure psi$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:suresh/sample.git/
psis-Mac-mini:sure psi$ git remote -v
origin git@github.com:suresh/sample.git/ (fetch)
origin git@github.com:suresh/sample.git/ (push)
psis-Mac-mini:sure psi$ git push origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. pls clarify

Comment: Of course `Repository not found`: the repo doesn't exist: see https://github.com/suresh?tab=repositories. Did you already created the repo on github? Or did you delete the repo on github recently?